# Python Social Auth - Facebook - Django: How do I obtain and use the users link attribute for Facebook?

Tags: python, django, facebook, python-social-auth

I have been setting up the Python Social Auth with Facebook and Django and I am trying to obtain the link, which I believe is the link to the user's profile with the application.

I have the setting:

```
FACEBOOK_AUTH_EXTRA_ARGUMENTS = {'link'}
```

in my `settings.py` which I believe should obtain the link from the user when they login on top of all the default things.

Then when I want to try and put the link onto a template I do this:

```
<p>Test: {{ wishlist.user.link }}</p>
```

The `{{wishlist.user.link}}` part returns nothing. If I try to print the `user.link` in my views it says link doesn't exist. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get the answer using the syntax...

```
{{ social.uid }}
```

`social.uid` is available by default so you should be able to use it right away.